# Need to compare two columns from two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to compare a first column value between two dataframes and change value of second column by multiplying the value with second column of second dataframe

dataframe1

```
Money   Currency
 34       USD
 31       EUR
 20       JPY
```

dataframe2

```
Curr   Value
EUR     1.21
JPY     0.78
```

my expected output

```
 Money            Currency
  34                 USD
  37.51(31*1.21)     USD
  15.6(20*0.78)      USD
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with second DataFrame and multiple by [`Series.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) (there is `fill_value` for multiple by `1` if no match value like for `USD` in sample data, so is created missing value):

```
s = dataframe2.set_index('Curr')['Value']
dataframe1['Money'] = dataframe1['Currency'].map(s).mul(dataframe1['Money'], fill_value=1)

dataframe1['Currency'] = 'USD'

print (dataframe1)
   Money Currency
0  34.00      USD
1  37.51      USD
2  15.60      USD
```

**Detail**:

```
print (dataframe1['Currency'].map(s))
0     NaN
1    1.21
2    0.78
Name: Currency, dtype: float64
```

Comment: And I have replace currency value also to USD after conversion happens

Comment: @VigneshR - Answer was edited, added `dataframe1['Currency'] = 'USD'`